# Modernizer is not defined

Tags: undefined, modernizr

I have included this code in my script. Can someone tell me step by step how to install Modernizer in a page, in English layman point of view?

```
if(Modernizer.geolocation){
    alert("geolocation is supported");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can search for "install Modernizer".

Comment: You can use the script tag from here to get started: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Modernizr is not defined" happens when you try to reference it somewhere in a code but have not included it previously.

You may have your

```
if(Modernizer.geolocation)
```

call before `Modernizr` is included, or you have not included it at all. There is also a case when `Modernizr` is included but within asynchronous script (in that case, there might be something like `<script src="modernizr.js" async></script>`).

How to include Modernizr - the easiest way?

First choose your detects - a set of features your custom built version of `Modernizr` will test:
https://modernizr.com/download

Than save it as `modernizer.js` somewhere in your source tree, for example `'js/modernizr.rs'`. Include it in a `script` tag before first `Modernizr` call. Like:

```
<script src="js/modernizr.rs"></script>
<script>
if(Modernizer.geolocation){
    alert("geolocation is supported");
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks,I found out where my problem is?

Comment: @DhafraSanchez's you welcome. If you find my answer helpful, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).